# MongoDB authentication starts failing unexpectedly in successfully running spring boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've been encountering weird issue in my spring boot app which uses mongo db.
Application starts successfully and working successfully until Mongo authentication started failing unexpectedly, there are other apps also using that same mongo server but they didn't get such kind of exception.
Mongo Configuration in spring boot is as follows :

```
@Bean
@Primary
public MongoClient mongoClient()
{
MongoCredential cred = MongoCredential.creatScramSha1Credential("mongoUser","admin", "password".toCharArray());
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                                               .connectTimeOut(5000)
                                               .maxConnectionIdleTime(60000)
                                               .minConnectionsPerHost(1)
                                               .maxWaitTime(30000)
                                               .build();
return new MongoClient(serverList, cred, options);
}
```

Also, before this exception starts popping up, app successfully does read/write operations.
How does suddenly mongo stops authenticating same user which was working just fine.

Comment: What do the exception and the corresponding log entry from the server tell you?

Comment: @Joe it is telling exactly as  : Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism:SCRAM-SHA-1, userName:'mongoUser', source:'admin', password=<hidden>,mechanismProperties={}};nested Exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException : Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism:SCRAM-SHA-1, userName:'mongoUser', source:'admin', password=<hidden>,mechanismProperties={}};

Comment: The mongod log node you are trying to connect to should have a bit more detail.